# React SSR with matched routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I am new to the SSR topic. I am trying to create a server that on a specific GET request (`/:subject/:type/:keyword/:version/:bizId`) will render an App component + Home component on the server, and send the rendered result to the client.

It works fine, but my problem is when I try to use BrowserRouter on the client side after getting the initial content. For some reason, the Link component from react-router-dom tries to send a GET request to the server, and I can't figure out why.

App.js:

```
const App = (props) => {
 ...some path configuration

  let paths = {
    homePath,
    servicesPath,
    aboutPath,
    contactPath
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header paths={paths} />
      {renderRoutes(props.route.routes)}
    </div>
  )
};

export default {
  component: App
};
```

Header.js:

```
export default props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={props.paths.homePath}>Home</Link>
      <Link to={props.paths.servicesPath}>Services</Link>
      <Link to={props.paths.aboutPath}>About</Link>
      <Link to={props.paths.contactPath}>Contact Us</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Routes.js:

```
export default [
  {
    ...App,
    routes: [
      {
        ...Home,
        path: '/'
      },
      {
        ...Services,
        path: '/services'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I'll be glad to provide with more details, just didn't know what exactly to post.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure that my problem is that the paths defined in Routes.js aren't relative, but I don't know how to make them relative to the requested url.

Comment: Are you using a library like NextJS for SSR?

Comment: Nope, I don't use nextJS. I found it to be inconvenient.

Comment: What? How can it be inconvenient? NextJS is the best, most used, SSR library for React there is. You said you're new to SSR, more the reason to use it. Anyway, I don't want to steer off topic. If your router is doing a request to your server it means your app doesn't understand the difference between the client and the server.

Comment: Maybe i left NextJS too quickly. Do you think it'll be easier to achieve what I need with NextJS?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use **Create React App** with a minor tweak (patch) to support server-side rendering (SSR). The routes may look something like this:

```
import Router from 'universal-router';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/books',
    query: graphql`
      query BookListQuery {
        ...BookList
      }
    `,
    components: () => [import('./BookList')],
    render:([BookList], data) => ({
      title: 'Our Books',
      component: <BookList data={data} />
    })
  },
  {
    path: '/books/:id',
    query: graphql`
      query BookDetailsQuery($id: ID!) {
        book: node(id: $id) {
          title
          ...BookDetails
        }
      }
    `,
    components: () => [import('./BookDetails')],
    render: ([BookDetails], data) => ({
      title: data.title,
      component: <BookDetails data={data} />
    })
  },
];

export default new Router(routes, {
  resolveRoute(ctx) {
    // TODO: How each route should be handled, for example
    //       we can load application chunks and call GraphQL API
  };
});
```

You can find the complete example here:

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-firebase-starter